# Exclude files from Play framework production build

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin, sbt-web

I'd like to use sbt-web to process my client-side assets. I have some source files that are going to be fed into sbt-web, and sbt-web is going to output some distribution files.

Is there a way to tell Play framework to exclude these source files (e.g. unminified javascript, etc) from the deployment build when building for production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sbt-filter](https://github.com/rgcottrell/sbt-filter) is what you are looking for. You can follow description at the Github page but basically you have to enable the plugin in your `build.sbt`, add it to the pipeline and write filter configuration.

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(SbtWeb)

pipelineStages := Seq(filter)
```

For example to exclude a unminified javascripts you use:

```
includeFilter in filter := "*.js"

excludeFilter in filter := "*.min.js"
```

Comment: Just to add up, you have to enable the **sbt-filter** plugin in your `project/plugins.sbt` first, by adding this line `addSbtPlugin("com.slidingautonomy.sbt" % "sbt-filter" % "1.0.1")`, or else the `filter` symbol will be unresolved in your `build.sbt`.

Comment: This project appears to be dormant and even the README.md examples seem to be incorrect (e.g. I can't get the "javascripts/working" example to filter).